How to reset radio buttons on reactive forms in angular 14
In my application, I need to reset input type radio button on cancel button click in reactive forms.
<form [formGroup]="form1">
<button click="save()">save</button>
<button click="Cancel()">Cancel</button>
<div *ngFor*="let items of itemarray">
<input type = "radio" (change)="onChange()" name="test_{{id}}" id="test_{{id}}">None</input>
<input type = "radio" name="test_{{id}}" id="test_{{id}}">Full</input>
</div>
</form>

in TS file

onChange()
{
this.form1.markasdirty();
}

cancel()
{
this.form1.reset()
this.itemarray = this.originalArry();
}

reset option is not resetting radio button existing value on cancel button. Also assigning fresh data to itemarray but its not reflecting on UI.
I tried below code on cancel button -
this.form1.get(this.form1.value).reset();

here I'm getting this.form1.value as undefine

Your's inputs are not related with any FormControl (have no formControlName or formControl attribute). Please, edit your question adding how you create the formGroup. BTW, if you have a originalArry be carefully to use a "copy" of the array. If you use, e.g. this.copyArray=this.originalArray you have an unique array, you need make a deep copy: this.copyArray=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.originalArray)); if is an array of objects or simply this.copyArray=[...this.originalArray] if is an array of string/numbers or boolean.

@Eliseo - Thanks for comment. I'm creating radio dynamically, so wont be able to use formControlName . I will try  with deepcopy, as you suggested.

in Angular you have "variables" in .ts and show the values of this variables in .html. when you have an input, you can use "two-ways-binding" (a variable show the value in the input, and when you change the input, the variable change). This way is called template driven forms (aka ngModel). Another way is using reactive Forms
